# Detect screen press at certain times

Tags: java, android, arrays, time, detection

So, I am fairly new to java and android programming and I am having an issue coming up with the code for a project I am working on.  Basically, there is a list of times, which I assume need to be stored as an array.  Once the game has started, it needs to do one of two things:

1. If the user presses the screen within a few milliseconds of a time in the array, it will register as a hit and increase count.
2. If the user presses the screen outside of the "hit" time, it will register as a miss and reset count to 0.

Now, I have all the elements in place to make everything work (increasing count on screen press, etc).  My issue is with the code to detect if the user pressed the screen on time or not.  I have tried doing some searches, but I can't figure it out.  Here is a small list of the times that are "good" hits:

- 0.25
- 0.84
- 1.03
- 1.60
- 2.3
- 2.6
- 2.9

These times can change a little and some can be removed if its not working correctly.  The biggest issue I can think of is making sure that it starts the timer when the game starts so the times match up.  The current timer starts at 100 and counts down 1 second at a time and when it reaches zero it takes the user to the game over screen.  This of course can change if there is a better way to do it or a different way that it has to happen to make the screen press detection code work.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user misses a time entirely - i.e they don't press anything?

Comment: If they don't press anything, it will also trigger as a miss.

Answer (score 1):

Really, all you need to do is log the current system time at the time the game starts. Then, it's just:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//...
System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

Then, to check if you're within the bounds set at any point in the array (which I will assume is an array of doubles):

```
public final static int THRESHOLD_MSEC = 100;
public boolean isHit(double time) {
    int time = System.currentTimeMillis - startTime;
    for(double d : array)
        if(Math.abs(d-time) < THRESHOLD_MSEC) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then, elsewhere in your application, you can handle what happens when `isHit` returns either true or false. I'm not going to write that part for you. A point of note: a few milliseconds is *nothing* in comparison to human reflexes, and *nobody* will be able to make that time.

Comment: I understand the 2nd section of code, but I am having a hard time with the 1st section of code.  Never worked with System.currentTimeMillis() before.  `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();` I assume goes right at the start when the player first has control of the game.  What's I am not understanding is the 2nd line and how it relates to the 2nd section of code you posted.